# How can I verify if TLS 1.2 is supported in c#

Tags: c#, tls1.2

in my c# Project i want to check from my client if the TLS version is 1.2. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: You can check the .NET version, from here you know what is default supported by the framework

Comment: @lordkain TLS support is also OS-specific.

Comment: thnx, i know. And I also know that the .net framework 4.0 support TLS1.1 and not TLS1.1

Comment: Why do you ask? TLS 1.2 was added with 4.5.2, the earliest supported version. Just ensure that you use 4.5.2 or later

Comment: @CodeCaster Are you talking about Vista? 4.5.2 won't even install on XP.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos you can install 4.5.2 on Vista SP2 and 2008 SP2, but those OSes don't support TLS 1.2 (you can install it, but that's not supported by MS is what I mean).

Comment: @CodeCaster so i need to check on which OS my Client is running?

Answer (score 0):

Not directly answer to your question: you can support relevant version of tls by:

```
System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls;
```

Comment: Which only works if .NET already supports 1.2, ie if it is 4.5.2 and later

Comment: I tried this and use .NET 4.5.2 but nevertheless i don´t know if the OS support this TLS version right?